# Android: Content provider security

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-security

I am learning some basic knowledge in Android. Now, I am dealing with `ContentProvider`. Many post said that we should use content provider for data sharing between application.

After a few days researching, I totally agree that it is quite convenience to use `ContentProvider` in Android. However, there is a security problem.

We all know that content provider uri always has `content://` at the beginning. By that way, I can use some tools (Total Commander for example) to find out the word `content://` in a specific file and figure out everything we need to access the data.

Following, I am able to create an application which access the data of another application by using that `uri`.

Did I miss something in `ContentProvider` which are use to prevent this security problem from happening?

## ADD 1:

We know that we are able to convert from an `.apk` file to source. By that way, the hackers are able to figure out the `uri` which is used for access the data.

After a few hours research, I know we can set permission (`readPermission` and `writePermission`) but hackers could know exactly where it is and they can add the permission to their apps and continue to access our app's data.

Is there anyway to hide or just allow some specific apps access to our data by using `ContentProvider`?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @0X0nosugar: Thank you for your comment. `readPermission` and `writePermission` did not solve my problems. About the `grantUriPermission`, can you give me an example of it. I did some research but the result is not clear. Thank you in advance!